# does tailwindcss divide width not work for multiple grid rows?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a tailwind grid with a set amount of columns.
I resize the set amount of columns based on breakpoints.

The amount of items inside the grid is variable.

Now i have to put dividers between the columns that are on the same row.

I tried to use [Tailwind's divide width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/divide-width)
But not getting the results i expected

It puts a border on the first column of the second row aswell,
I expected that the divider would reset when a new row was introduced.

Example

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 divide-x-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>div 3</div>
  <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

[example in tailwindplay](https://play.tailwindcss.com/9FkJCjpLLv)

was i stupid for thinking this would just work?
I would like to prevent having to use something like

`[&>*:nth-child(even)]:border-l-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `divide-x-*` classes are indeed unsuitable for use with multi-row elements. Essentially, the rule is simple, and largely equivalent to

```css
.divide-x-key * + * {
  border-left: value;
}
```

If you wanted to avoid using `[&>*:nth-child(even)]:border-l-1` et al, you could consider using `clip-path` to hide the left classes like:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.7"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-2 divide-x-2 lg:grid-cols-4 ml-[calc(theme(divideWidth.2)*-1)] [clip-path:inset(0_0_0_theme(divideWidth.2))]">
  <div class="pl-[theme(divideWidth.2)]">div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>div 3</div>
  <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does indeed seem to work as I would want it.
How does it actually work? does it hide the unwanted borders in the left margin?

Comment: It works by clipping anything from `2px` from the left edge of the element, exactly where the left border lines would appear.